# Custom vb script titlebar caption

Tags: vbscript

The "Windows Script Host" titlebar caption can be blanked out by replacing "Wscript.Echo" with "Msgbox" but what should I do if I want to see a custom titlebar caption?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). You specify the title as the 3<sup>rd</sup> argument of the `MsgBox()` function:

```
MsgBox "Message text", vbOKOnly, "Title"
```

Comment: Done! Sorry I did not think to do that before... I am new here ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Cscript, `.Echo` displays text in console window.
For Wscript, `.Echo` displays text in a dialog window.

To customize this window, either code will do:
`MsgBox "Your text", 32, "Window Title"` or
`WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Message",, "Some title", 48`

For messagebox, user needs to dismiss with button click, or equivalent keyboard shortcut
For popup box, the box can be dismissed either by user, or timeout

The numbers in each command tell script engine what buttons & icons to display in GUI box.